# Pip install dlib stuck for the Face recognition python library

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to perform the face recognition python library in Windows 7. As per the steps provided, I did the below

1. Installed Visual Studio C++ development tool
2. Installed CMAKE tool and added the path to the system env variable
3. Created a new python virtual env 3.8 in anaconda
4. `pip install cmake` - successfully  completed
5. `pip install dlib` - This is stuck at the setup line.

I referred a number of blogs but don't get a solution. Some referred as RAM size but I don't this is to do with RAM space.

Comment: The issue is resolved finally by downloading the wheel zip file and doing pip install <downloaded file location> after unzipping.

Answer (score -2):

After installing the C++ development kit, python and CMake. create a folder anywhere on your computer, while pressing the shift key click right click and open Windows PowerShell for that folder created.

In the PowerShell type:- git clone https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition.git

once the cloning is done, enter the folder face_recognition created inside the folder you created and check whether a file name Setup.py is there or not if it's there which it should be, open windows PowerShell or cmd for that folder again.

and type: - python setup.py install

this will automatically install the latest version of dlib, and face_recognition necessary library.

To check go to your anaconda and type pip list. You will see that your CMake, dlib, face_recognition all three libraries have been installed.